# How to maintain controlled input which are added dynamically on user click with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a form component, where you can add multiple inputs on click. I am using useState to store data from all of the inputs, but the problem is I am receiving a message that my inputs are uncontrolled

## State data structure

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: '',
    titleNum: '',
    meta: [
      {
        content: '',
        contentNum: '',
        details: '',
        tags: ''
      }
    ]
  });
```

The idea is to dynamically add multiple objects via form to meta array

## onChange events added to inputs

```
const { title, titleNum, meta } = formData;

  const handleMainChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    let metaContent = [...meta];
    metaContent[index] = { ...metaContent[index], [name]: value };
    setFormData({ ...formData, meta: metaContent });
  };
```

## Adding and removing inputs

```
const handleAddInput = () => {
    setFormData(prevState => ({
      meta: [
        ...prevState.meta,
        { content: '', contentNum: '', details: '', tags: '' }
      ]
    }));
  };

  const handleRemove = index => {
    let metaContent = [...meta];
    metaContent.splice(index, 1);
    setFormData({ meta: metaContent });
  };
```

## Submit and looping through all META

```
const onFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createAccount(formData, history);
  };

  const renderList = meta.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(item);
    return (
      <AddMeta
        key={index}
        index={index}
        meta={item}
        handleChange={e => handleSubChange(e, index)}
        handleRemove={() => handleRemove(index)}
      />
    );
  });
```

## AddMeta Component

```
const AddMeta = ({ index, meta, handleChange, handleRemove }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='row valign-wrapper'>
        <div className='col s3'>
          <h5 className='indigo-text text-lighten-1'>Add Meta - {index + 1}</h5>
        </div>
        <div className='col s9'>
          <button onClick={() => handleRemove(index)} className='btn red'>
            Remove Meta Content
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Content Text'
          name='content'
          value={meta.content || ''}
          onChange={e => handleChange(e, index)}
          autoComplete='off'
        />
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Content Number'
          name='contentNum'
          value={meta.contentNum || ''}
          onChange={e => handleChange(e, index)}
          autoComplete='off'
        />
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <textarea
          className='materialize-textarea'
          type='text'
          placeholder='Details'
          name='details'
          value={meta.details || ''}
          onChange={e => handleChange(e, index)}
          autoComplete='off'
        />
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Tags'
          name='tags'
          value={meta.tags || ''}
          onChange={e => handleChange(e, index)}
          autoComplete='off'
        />
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

I appreciate any attempt to solve this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: I created a [demo from what you've shared](https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-react-input-uncontrolled). Have a look. I do not see any issues with it. No warnings/errrors. Perhaps there's more information that you would like to share.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `|| ''` on your inputs value. Their value should always be tied to your state (which should be `''` when you add a new meta).

Comment: Thanks for going through my complex problem. At the moment warning is displayed once I add another set of inputs. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Check this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-waterfall-x2g4k and see if there is any difference with your code